# WebView load images asynchronously from Database

Tags: android, database, webview

I would like to load images referenced in HTML asynchronously from my local Database.

Right now all I can do is to replace the `abc.jpg` part of `<img src="abc.jpg">` by `data:image/jpg;base64, img_base64_string>`, but this has to be done before the HTML get's rendered. I would like to show the HTML page as fast as possible and then load the images.

- How to trigger a loading event to load an image from the DB?
- How to correctly set the loaded image in HTML without converting it to base64?

Comment: use custom ContentProvider and override its openFile method

Comment: A custom ContentProvider doesn't really help here, because you still need to have a file path in the end - which I don't have because the image is stored in a database.

Comment: no, you dont need to have a file path, why do you think so?

Comment: I would really like to see some ContentProvider.openFile() code which returns a ParcelFileDescriptor from a byte[] → I'm new to the ContentProvider stuff.

Comment: agree, but there is no such thing, you can only get it from a file or from a socket, the latter is the only way you can do to meet your goal

Comment: or you can create a temp file and create a ParcelFileDescripror from that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create a ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe() to copy the database file through streams to the WebView.

LocalImageContentProvider.java

```
public class LocalImageContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.local.provider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+ AUTHORITY +"/image");

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) {
        String filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();

        // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#createPipe%28%29     
        // [0] is the reader, [1] is the writer
        ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = null;

        try {
            pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();

            // copy DB file through pipe to WebView
            new Thread(new PipeRunnable(
                    getInputStreamFromDbFile(filename),
                    new AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1])) )
            .start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (pipe[0]);
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <application>

        <!-- 'activity -->

        <provider android:exported="false"
            android:name=".provider.LocalImageContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.local.provider"
        />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

To load images in the WebView use the ContentProvider URI + "/image.jpg":
`<img src="content://com.example.local.provider/image/29.jpg"></img>`