# Combining html UI with native android app

Tags: java, android, html, web-applications

I want to know if I could combine html UI  elements
into the native android app and put values (images and Strings) fetched from a database directly to the html UI.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can use a `WebView` in order to show HTML content inside your app.

Comment: because my team could design a good UI but in html & css so i want to include it in my application , if i used webview it will allow me to handle buttons (created in html ) actions and add images to it ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's absolutely not worth. Your team should learn how to design good interfaces in pure Android or use a WebApp framework like Cordova, Titanium and so on.

Comment: @Grender thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is using a WebView to show a html content!
One example about this:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: if i used WebView it will allow me to add images fetched from database to certain frames in the UI ?

Comment: this link can help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29">http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29  and for the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148793/webview-load-images-asynchronously-from-database if yes, please check as a good answer, thanks!